# Show Records In Table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, html-table

I have records from database like this.

[image: My Records]

I Want to Show a table like this
  [image: Table to show Like]

> the Days goes up to 32 and is by default 1 to 32. I have to insert the
>   records where the days match.

Because the method i tried is too much messy and also not working. 
Can you guys suggest me some ways to Do it? 
I need to show it in HTML table.
any language is Good.. I just need the idea.
preferably MVC C#

**UPDATE**
Thank you both... I got idea from both of you (unlimit and Joe Enos) and I did it. Can you  help me with one more same problem? What if `Area 1` has another record of `2 hours` on same day. I need to show them `separately`. How will I show the record in same day?

[image]

Comment: Are you pulling this data from a database? If yes, then check `pivot`. It might help.

Comment: using pivot for only 1 value (hour here) is good. But i actually have multiple values(2-3 data) to show , for which, sadly pivot is really not the thing to use.

Comment: I think you will have to loop through the data and create the table yourself.

Comment: Yah, that is i am trying to do... looking for ideas how to do it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this, I have not checked for correctness of syntax etc.

```
Dictionary<string,int[]> data = new Dictionary<string,int[]>();

foreach (var record in database)
{
        if (!data.ContainsKey(record["location"]))
        {
            int[] days = new int[32];
            days[record["day"]] = record["hour"];                
            data.Add(record["location"], days);
        }
        else
        {
            int[] days = data[record["location"]];
            days[record["day"]] = record["hour"]; 
            //data[record["location"]] = days;
        }
}
```

The variable `data` should have your data in the format you want. You then loop through this and populate the html table.

**EDIT in response to the comment by OP**

If there are more than one set of hours per day and the number of this set is not fixed, then you can use something like this.

```
 Dictionary<string,ArrayList> day = new Dictionary<string,ArrayList>();
 Dictionary<string,day> location = new Dictionary<string,day>();
```

Here `day` dictionary will hold keys like `Day 1, Day 2, Day 3, etc...` and the value `ArrayList` will hold an array of hours in that day.

The `location` dictionary will hold keys like `Area 1, Area 2, etc...` and the value will be the `day` dictionary.

Maybe this will give you some hints on how to go about solving this.

Comment: You don't need to reassign the array to the dictionary (`data[record["location"]] = days;`). It's an array (reference type), which you're pulling from the dictionary, and setting one of the values. You can leave that line out altogether, and since it's the same reference, you're fine.

Comment: Thank you guys both... I got idea from both of you and i did it. Can you guys help me with one more same problem? What if `Area 1  has another record of 12 hours on same day. How will i show the record in same day?

Comment: Why don't you add the hours to the existing hours?

Comment: Sorry can't do that, I need the Hours to be seperate.

Comment: @Ruchan See my updated answer for some hints to solve this new problem.

Comment: `Dictionary<string,day> location = new Dictionary<string,day>();` cannot be done. However i get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to convert your data into something more usable. Once you do that, turning it into rows is easy.

Build a class representing an area, which contains an array of values, for each of the 32 slots. As you're reading the data, populate the appropriate values in your array, something like:

```
class Area {
    public Area() { Values = new int[32]; }
    public int[] Values { get; set; }
    public int AreaNumber { get; set; }
}

var areas = new List<Area>();
foreach (var record in databaseRecords) {
    var area = // find area from list based on AreaNumber. If not there, add it
    area[record.Day - 1] = record.Hour;
}
```

Now you've got a list of Areas, each with a 32-item array. Now your HTML table can be built with a two-level loop, first looping through all areas, then looping through the 32 items in the array.